# Inject a result of calling a method inside config.xml datasource in spring

Tags: java, xml, spring

I have a spring project and in database.properties the value is encrypted.I have a class to decrypt that value and I am calling that inside config.xml file

database.properties

```
database.password=AAAAAhhhhhhiiiiii
```

config.xml

```
<environments default="development">
    <environment id="development">
        <transactionManager type="JDBC"/>

        <dataSource type="POOLED">
            <property name="driver" value="${database.driver}"/>
            <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
            <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
            <property name="password" value="#{com.me.portal.rest.security.encryption.PasswordEncryption.decryptPropertyValue('${database.password}')}"/>
            <property name="driver.oracle.net.CONNECT_TIMEOUT" value="${database.connecttimeout}"/>
            <property name="poolMaximumActiveConnections" value="100"/>
        </dataSource>
    </environment>
</environments>
```

PasswordEncryption is the class that has the decrypt method.But when I send requests to some endpoints it gives status as 'fail'.Is there something wrong in the way I call the decrypt method inside config.xml.

Comment: Have you checked log files? Usually some hints could be found there

Comment: Does it work using the plaintext password and no decryption method?

Comment: @ArmandoBallaci yes.It works fine with plaintext

Comment: Could you then set debug=true and share the stacktrace?